# download mp4,flv url link from youtube videoID

Tags: android, youtube-dl

I want to know the `working of youtube-dl.` As i want to make a `youtube downloader` for android. I simply **want to download mp4 or flv formats from youtube** URLs.

How `youtube-dl videoID` returns the `downlaodable URL`. I simply want to know how can i do it in **Android without youtube-dl.**

Because i don't know how to run and install python Script to PHP server or Android end.

Comment: If you are using ubutnu, try this command `man youtube-dl` or refer the documentation. Actually i also wanna implement that functionality downloading youtube videos. lack on time not able to do. Once you done it if possible please share the code with me

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl [is open-source](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/LICENSE), so it's no secret how it works. You can simply read the source code. A good start would be the [youtube extractor](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py).